# Help with MacBook Pro (unibody) keyboard damage

Tags: macbook-pro, unibody

I have some scratches on my <kbd>A</kbd> key. I don't actually know where it came from but it looks deep and melted. Could it have actually melted due to the screen heat? And if so, why only that letter?

Also, is there a way to easily clean the keyboard? Or do i have to disassemble my notebook and put it all back together again?

Answer (score 1):

> Could it have "melted" due to the screen heat?

No. Impossible.

> Also, is there a way to easily clean the keyboard?

You can pop out the keys if you like ([see this YouTube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSpPlMdGvVI)). I would advise against pulling out the entire keyboard as you won't be able to clean it any quicker and may damage it (depending on your dexterity) in the process. It is also a lengthy process that requires removal of the logicboard ([hit up iFixit for details](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009-Upper-Case-Replacement/6040/1)). Technically, the keyboard is attached to the top panel of the notebook (unlike the pre-unibody MacBook Pros).

As for a cleaning solution, you can use any monitor cleaner or a high concentrate (99%) [isopropyl alcohol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B5JT8C) (70% will if you can't find the 99%, but not preferred). Apply it using q-tips or a small micro-fiber rag.

Comment: so what's your guess on the keyboard scratch/melt? will upload a pic, but thanks for the cleaning help :)

Comment: my phone's camera can't actually capture the scratches, but what do you think could be the reason?

Comment: I have no idea. Without seeing it, I can't even hypothesize. But I can assure you that it can't possibly be the LCD as even after hours of use, they get lukewarm at best.